# Enable button according to NSSet object count using ReactiveCocoa

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I'm trying to use ReactiveCocoa to enable a button depending on if the number of objects in an NSMutableSet instance is greater than zero.

I am using the following code, but am experiencing a crash at runtime. Any ideas?

```
RAC(self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem, enabled) = [RACSignal combineLatest:@[self.selectedRows] reduce:^(NSMutableSet *set){
    return @([set count] > 0);
}];
```

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSetM map:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9671d10'

Comment: When you `+combineLatest:`, the array is an array of *signals*, not keypaths.

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn your `selectedRows` property into a signal:

```
RAC(self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem, enabled) = [RACSignal combineLatest:@[RACAbleWithStart(self.selectedRows)] reduce:^(NSMutableSet *set){
    return @([set count] > 0);
}];
```

Comment: Also, this doesn't need a `+combineLatest:reduce:` at all. It can be written with `-map:` instead.

Comment: Thanks, this gets me past the crash but doesn't seem to enable the button when an object is added to `self.selectedRows`. To give a little context - this is a delete button that should be enabled when rows in a tableView are highlighted and is disabled when nothing is selected.

Comment: @Alexander The collection has to be [KVO-compliant](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002178-BAJEAIEE), since `RACAble` is just glorified KVO. If you're modifying the collection in place (instead of replacing it), the necessary notifications are not generated automatically.

Comment: The above code will work perfectly if one wraps changes to `selectedRows` with `[self willChangeValueForKey:@"selectedRows"]` and `[self didChangeValueForKey:@"selectedRows"]`

Answer (score 0):

Thats sad to know that NSarry, NSMutableArray do not support KVO. While doing something similar

But thankfully, UIViewController is KVO compliant.

```
//create a readonly property selectionCount
@property (nonatomic, readonly)NSInteger selectionCount;
...

//Implement the getter method
-(NSInteger)selectionCount{
    return self.arrSelection.count;
}
...

RAC(self.btnConfirm, enabled) = [RACSignal combineLatest:@[RACAbleWithStart(self.selectionCount)] reduce:^(NSNumber *count){
        return @([count integerValue] > 0);
    }];
```